# kafka connect - How to filter schema metadata from payload

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to remove schema from the payload and here are the configurations

**connector.properties**

```
name=test-source-mysql-jdbc-autoincrement
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
tasks.max=1
connection.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/employee_db?user=root&password=root
table.whitelist=testemp
mode=incrementing
incrementing.column.name=employee_id
topic.prefix=test-mysql-jdbc-
```

and below are my **worker.properties**

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092


key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter

key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false


internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets

offset.flush.interval.ms=10000
plugin.path=C:\Users\name\Desktop\kafka\libs
```

**output:**

```
{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"int32","optional":false,"field":"employee_id"},{"type":"string","optional":false,"field":"first_name"}],"optional":false,"name":"testemp"},"payload":{"employee_id":2,"first_name":"test"}}
```

**excepted output:**

```
{"payload":{"employee_id":2,"first_name":"test"}}
```

I tried disabling value.converter.schemas.enable= false in worker as suggested in  [here](https://rmoff.net/2017/09/06/kafka-connect-jsondeserializer-with-schemas.enable-requires-schema-and-payload-fields/) still no effect

Am i missing something?

Comment: Why do you want to disable the schema?

Comment: "business requirements" you know how they work.

Comment: X-D Use Avro for all-round win.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two option to fix it:

- Remove `value.converter` property from your connector configuration (You use same `value.converter`)
- Set `value.converter.schemas.enable=false` in your connector configuration.

Schema is added to message, because you have overwritten value converter and didn't disable schema (by default for `JsonConverter` schema is enabled). From Kafka Connect point of view you used completely new Converter (it will not use properties from global configuration)

If you will disable schema your message will be as follow:

```js
{
    "employee_id": 2,
    "first_name":"test"
}
```